# build of create-react-app --typescript api call returns You need to enable JavaScript to run this app. on deployed?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, express

it works perfectly fine on localhost but i cannot make api request when deployed, the api call returns

```
You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.
```

i have npm run build the app, my server sends file to it:

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
      // Serve any static files
      this.app.use(express.static(path.join('../../frontend/build')));
      // Handle React routing, return all requests to React app
      this.app.get('*', (req, res) => {
        res.sendFile(path.join('../../frontend/build', 'index.html'));
      });
    }
```

this works perfectly fine with create-react-app but not in create-react-app --typescript? help?

Answer (score 0):

The error message seems to imply that javascript is not enabled in your browser. Which means that the change might be in system configuration/settings rather that the build.

Each browser has a different way of enabling/disabling javascript but you can search for it on google and change your settings accordingly. For example the procedure for Firefox is detailed here: https://www.technipages.com/firefox-enable-disable-javascript

Comment: but it is running on my localhost perfectly, it only occurs on the deployed site?

Comment: with the same client? As in...are you trying to access the localhost and the deployed site on the same system/browser?

Comment: yes, same browser, perfectly fine on localhost but not when deploy, that's when the api calls returns You need to run javascript

Comment: Can you try to add the following html `<noscript>Message!</noscript>` on any static page that would be able to run without api calls? it would atleast tell you whether the issue is server side or client side